# Linear system solution orthogonal to a plane

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vector-spaces, systems-of-equations

I'm having trouble solving the following problem:

Consider the plane $K: \begin{cases}
x=t+1  \\
y=-t+2s-1 \\
z=s-1
\end{cases}$

and the linear system $\begin{cases}
-x+2y+az=3  \\
y-z=a \\
x+y-z=-9
\end{cases}$

Find $a \in \mathbb R$ such that the solution set of the system represents a line perpendicular to $K$.

I know that the dimension of the solution space $V$ is $dim(V)=n-rk(A|b)=1$ because of Rouché-Capelli theorem, therefore $rk(A|b)=rk(A)=2$ and I get $a=-2$ by setting the determinants of the 3x3 minors equal to $0$.

How can I check if the solution set is now orthogonal to $K$ ?

Comment: Based on the answer below, the problem has no solution. Perhaps there’s a typo in it?

Comment: @amd It's possible that it has no solution, I was more interested in the process of solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$A=\left[\begin{array}{rrr}-1&2&a\\0&1&-1\\1&1&-1\end{array}\right]$$ be the coefficient array of the linear system. As you know, solutions to the inhomogeneous system are of the form $v+w$ with $w\in\ker A$, which will be perpendicular to $K$ iff the space $\ker A$ is. This will occur when the normal $n$ to $K$ is an element of $\ker A$, so one way to solve this problem is to see if there’s a value of $a$ for which $An=0$.

We can find a normal $n$ by taking the cross product of two linearly independent vectors parallel to $K$, which can in turn be found by setting $s=1$, $t=0$ and vice-versa: $n=(1,-1,0)\times(0,2,1)=(-1,-1,2)$ and $$An=\left[\begin{array}{rrr}-1&2&a\\0&1&-1\\1&1&-1\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{rrr}-1\\-1\\2\end{array}\right]=\begin{bmatrix}2a-1\\-3\\-4\end{bmatrix}.$$ It’s clear from this that the problem has no solution.

Since you’ve already found the value of $a$ for which $A$ does not have full rank, a way to proceed from there would be to compute a basis vector for $\ker A$ and check that vector is perpendicular to the generators of $K$. This is essentially what Rafa Burdría does in [another answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2315079/265466).

Answer (score 1):

$u=(1,-1,0)$ and $v=(0,2,1)$ are parallel to $K$ $(k=(1,-1,0)t+(0,2,1)s+(1,-1,-1$))

$s=(0,1,1)$ is parallel to the set of solutions ($z=t;\;y-t=a\;;x+t+a-t=-9$)

$u·s\neq0$, so, it's not perpendicular.